# How to bind background colors of a certain column in WPF ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, styling

Right now I use alternating colors:

[image]

But for a certain column like Profit, I want to override the background color but with a binding, not a hardcoded color. I have a ProfitColor property in the same Binding class:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3c3c3c"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Coins}" Name="Tasks" Height="250" AlternationCount="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="25" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}">
                    
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="25" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Symbol" Width="90">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Symbol}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Capital" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Profit" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="PNL %" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Day %" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Hour %" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Min %" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Lowest" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="90">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.PriceDecimalDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Highest" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Net BTC/m" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
</Viewbox>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why you don't want to set a `Background` of e.g. `TextBlock` via binding? Otherwise I would advise to use `DataGrid`, where you have more possibilities to style the cells. See  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569942/wpf-datagrid-alternatingrowbackground-overriding-the-style-datatrigger-for-backg/54574388#54574388), which you can adjust to style the cell.

Comment: Hi I did that but I am getting this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462692/how-to-set-textblock-to-fill-the-wpf-listview-row-height Can datagrid solve this?

Comment: @Rekshino I did what you said but there is still a gap like in the above link. I am able to bind to a color but there is still margins in between the color backgrounds so they dont touch end to end.