# How to set TextBlock to fill the WPF ListView row height?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, styling

I set the background of my TextBlocks to different colors over the alternating colors. As you can see there is some gaps that are not colored in red:

[image]

Is there a way for me to remove those margins/spacing or stretch my TextBlock to completely fill those areas so the entire column region is colored?

Or is there a way to set the entire ListViewItem BG color?

Here is my XAML code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ProfitTracker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProfitTracker"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="1200">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3c3c3c"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Coins}" Name="Tasks" Height="250" AlternationCount="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="25" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}">

                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="25" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Symbol" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Symbol}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Lowest" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.LowestDailyPriceDisplay}" Foreground="#ff0000" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.PriceDecimalDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Highest" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.HighestDailyPriceDisplay}" Foreground="#00ff00" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Balance.UnitPriceDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Balance.AvailableAmountDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Capital" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Balance.TotalValueDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Profit" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Balance.ProfitDisplay}" Background="{Binding Path=Value.Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" Foreground="{Binding Path=Value.Balance.ProfitColor}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="PNL %" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Balance.ProfitPercentageDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Day %" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Hour %" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.PriceChangeInPercentHourlyDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Min %" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.PriceChangeInPercentMinutelyDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.LastHourVolumeInBtcDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Net BTC/m" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.LastMinuteVolumeInBtcDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

I tried DataTriggers but I am unable to set the ListViewItem background color based on its column header, for example "Profit":

```xml
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Name}" Value="Profit">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
```

Is there a way to access the column header from a listviewitem reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is, that control template for the `ListViewItem` has a `Border` with `Padding=2`. The only possibility to get rid of it I see to replace the control template with own. So you can add following to your `ListView` :

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">                        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>                                
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>                        
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For more details see also [ListView Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

If you need you can also customize the `VisualStateManager`.